# Copy of Deleted Record - Trigger or other way

Tags: oracle, triggers, copy

I need to create a copy of deleted records in a backup table when deleting records from PL/SQL Procedure. Which is the better way - Triggers or stored procedure or insert statement or there is any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

*"triggers or stored procedure or insert statement or there is any other approach."* With triggers you'll do an insert in another table. so, the third is not an new option.

If you can govern all the dml on the table, so yes, you can do it via stored procedure, but be sure it is an unique point, the code should be in one place, not spread in multiple procedures. From this point of view a trigger is better because you can't skip it.

On the other side. If you have bulk deletes maybe is better to have a stored procedure, because trigger will slow the dml. With stored proc you can have a separate treatment for bulks.

It depends on the issues you want to overcome.

Comment: Thank you. I am deleting Old (Historical) data. On testing we find that BULK DELETE performs better than trigger. Trigger is definitely easy to maintain. However, we choose BULK DELETE

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to not delete the record at all but to mark it as deleted. Of course the rest of the application needs to not select records that are marked as deleted. 
Probably not a viable option in an existing application.

Comment: I understand you want to soft delete. But, we are deleting historical data which will not be required for application now.